# MongoDB Aggregate Query Issues

Tags: mongodb

I am doing a query on MongoDB using a dataset that contains fields that are id, city, locations(as loc) population(as pop) and state. And the data contains redundant values (cities are duplicated). I have to extract the unique cities for a particular state but I am not sure what is wrong with my query. Here is my query `db.zipcodes.aggregate([{$match:{state:"NY"}},{$group:{_id:null, city:{$addToSet:"$city"},count:{$sum:1}}}])`and its not removing the duplicate cities.[image: MongoDB data]

Comment: You mean the `city` array has duplicates in the output?

Comment: The city is not an array. But records with the same city names exist.

Comment: As far as mongo is concerned there are no duplicates. Just because two documents have one similar field does not make them equal (aka duplicates). What is the output that you're looking for?

Comment: The addToSet operation will be creating an array

Answer (score 0):

use this aggregate

```
db.zipcodes.aggregate([
  {$match:{state:"NY"},
  {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 0
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$city', 
      'orig': {
        '$addToSet': '$$ROOT'
      }, 
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$orig'
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'orig.count': '$count', 
      'orig.city': 1, 
      'orig.state': 1
    }
  }, {
    '$replaceRoot': {
      'newRoot': '$orig'
    }
  }
])
```